What is the module spectrum over sphere spectrum?
Forgive me if this is a stupid question, I am a new hand at algebraic topology, and I learn that in stable homotopy theory, the sphere spectrum $\mathbb{S}$ is the unit object in $Sp$, and there is a slogan 'spectrum corresponds to abelian group and sphere spectrum corresponds to ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}$'.
So I can't help wondering:
$\textbf{Is the infinity category of modules over $\mathbb{S}$ exactly the whole infinity category Sp=Sp($Spc_{*}$)?}$
Indeed, if we denote the $HR$ as the Eilenberg-Maclane spectrum of the discrete commutative ring $R$, by 7.1.2 in HA, the infinity category of $Mod(HR)$ is equivalent to the infinity derived category of chain complexes of $R$ modules, this is far from the infinity category of spectrum $Sp$, but recall that sphere spectrum is the Eilenberg-Maclane spectrum of $\mathbb{F}_{1}$, and $\mathbb{F}_{1}$ is the 'field with one element', which is actually not like a 'usual field' and is also not the zero ring, so I guess this conclusion about 'module spectra over discrete ring' is $\textbf{invalid}$ in the case of $\mathbb{F}_{1}$, and it's not reasonable to consider the 'module spectrum over $\mathbb{S}$' as the derived category of '$\mathbb{F}_{1}$ modules'.
I also see in nlab which says that the model category of $\mathbb{S}$ modules actually 'present a symmetric monoidal infinity category of spectra', so does this imply the infinity category underlying the model category of $\mathbb{S}$ modules, which is the infnity category of $Mod(\mathbb{S})$, and is exactly the whole infinity category of spectra Sp?

Yes, it works just like $\mathbb{Z}$. Thinking about $\mathbb{F}_1$ here is a distraction. The general fact is that if $(C, \otimes)$ is any symmetric monoidal ($\infty$-)category it is canonically equivalent to the category of modules over the unit object.

Ok, that makes a lot of sense, indeed $\mathbb{F}_{1}$ is a distraction here.

This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer.

For the record, the sphere spectrum is very much not the Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum of F_1, for any model of F_1. At best it's the algebraic K-theory spectrum of F_1.

@JonathanBeardsley But I see this post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1628/kf-1-sphere-spectrum which says sphere spectrum is the Eilenberg-Maclane spectrum? So you mean in this post it actually says sphere spectrum is 'algebraic K theory spectrum'?

@Yang you may be getting confused by the overloaded notation. If A is an Abelian group then K(A,n) is the Eilenberg-MacLane space whose unique non-zero homotopy group is A, in degree n. If R is a ring, or field, then K(R) typically denotes the algebraic K-theory spectrum of that ring, which is a wildly different object.
